# Spring Web Flow - Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: java, spring-webflow

I am getting this error:

> Failed to load class `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` in spring web flow application implementation.

Comment: How are you building your project? Can we see the whole stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Please check dependency is loaded properly.

Use maven dependency tree command to make sure that no jar is conflicting.